# SP in SQL Addition and subtract

Tags: sql

I have a table called student.
there are  3 column (Name,Subject,Totalmarks)
I need to write a Stored procedure in SQL

This is the table :

```
Name   Subject  TotalMarks
 Aruna  OOP       50
 Sam    RDBMS     65
joney   OOP       70
```

write a SP to update student marks by5 if the subject is RDBMS and for OOP reduse by 3 marks?

Comment: School assignment? And you expect us to do it for you?

Comment: You don't need an SP, just a single `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a homework!